# .htaccess rewrite rule doesn't want to work what so ever

Tags: .htaccess

I've been using rewrite rules for a while, however this is strange.

the site is hosted on dev.domain.com, htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^order/([^/]+) order.php?id=$1 [QSA]
...
```

however when I go to http://dev.domain.com/order/4 the $_GET isn't being passed through, never had this sort of a problem before.

Comment: As in the rewrite isn't happening at all? Or you do get rewritten to order.php but without the query string? If the rewrite isn't happening, check that Apache's got [.htaccess enabled](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Rewrite happens, however the query string isn't being passed through

Comment: Surprisingly /order?id=4 works... may it be that .htaccess is disabled and it's using some mod to find the files? e.g. it doesn't find file order, so it searches for order.php and loads that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Nginx doesn't support .htaccess at all, have to do it it's own way..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) isn't limiting you. For example, if it is set to `None` - this would disable the whole .htaccess support completely and Apache would not look for .htaccess files on disk at all.
2. Check if [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled. This is known to produce unexpected results together with mod_rewrite.
3. Add "L" flag to the rule - `[L,QSA]` to stop rules execution at that point. Maybe you have other rules you did not post here, that affect the behavior.

Comment: Where would I check this? php.ini? or can I just do it through phpinfo()?

Comment: both `AllowOverride` and `MultiViews` are _Apache_ configuration. Check them in _httpd.conf_ and _virtual host_ configuration file

Comment: By the looks of it (from what i see in the comment above, stating that `/order?id=4` works) You do have `MultiViews` enabled.